# Does the Actor Model make most sense when dealing with concurrent in-memory state

Tags: java, concurrency, akka, actor

I've been looking into the Actor Model and Akka of late. As an OOP programmer I try to adhere to loose coupling and 'tell don't ask'. I also use messaging and events to communicate between bounded contexts. So, the patterns of actors make a lot of sense to me.

It is my understanding that the main motivation for using Actors is for managing state in a concurrent environment. Most of my day to day work involves writing backend business apps where the typical pattern is load an entity from a DB, check invariants, process a command, persist, raise event. If I have a high load and a lot of concurrent changes I might choose to use Event Sourcing rather than updating a database. So really my concurrency challenges are taken care of by my database layer.

So, my question is, is the Actor Model mainly an advantage where you dealing with fast changing, concurrent and in-memory state management such as an online multi player game.

Answer (score 2):

The actor model really helps with managing in-memory state and dramatically simplifies patterns/techniques like digital twins and memory image through the concurrency aspects.

There are other benefits: communication and latency being explicit in the model facilitating distribution is a major one... the closer an application is to a pure actor model the more able one is to present many replicas as one application with the attendant resiliency benefits.  There's also a failure-handling story (distinct from error-handling: they're rather distinct) which has a long history in building reliable systems.

But for the "backend business apps" you're talking about, where (from the talk of bounded contexts etc.) it seems you're following at least some DDD patterns, being able to keep state in memory is a pretty big win.

Consider a DDD aggregate noting that all access to the entities within that aggregate is through its root and noting that an aggregate forms a consistency boundary.  These both conform well to the actor model: the model's concurrency guarantees only hold when the actor's internal state is only accessible via the actor and the consistency boundary is trivially satisfied by encoding operations on the aggregate as messages/commands to the actor and relying on the one-message-at-a-time processing.  So it's reasonable to model each instance of an aggregate as an actor.

For simplicity, I'm going to assume (without loss of generality, but the one-aggregate-multiple-entity case introduces some complexity around preserving an illusion to the outside of one-message-at-a-time: the broad approach there in Akka terms is to map the aggregate to a sharded entity (there is a terminological mismatch...) and the entities in the aggregate to (likely persistent) child actors of that entity) that the aggregate contains a single entity.

A request comes in, we resolve the aggregate root for the request, and we have a `Map<AggregateRoot, ActorRef<AggregateCommand>>` (I'm using the typed API here, and we can assume that the map is concurrent) tracking the active in-memory instances of the aggregate.  If there's already an instance in memory, we translate the request into an `AggregateCommand` and send it to the actor (we'll probably be using the ask pattern so that we can return a different response for whether the command was accepted or rejected); if there isn't already an instance in memory, we'll spawn one and save it in the map before proceeding as before.

As a direct translation of the old logic, our aggregate actor will on every command load state for its entity from the DB, verify that certain invariants hold, process the command to update the in-memory state, persist that updated state and raise an event (presumably some sort of transactional outbox pattern is in use, otherwise there will be situations where no event was actually raised even though the state was updated...).

It's not clear what strategy you're taking with respect to concurrent command execution (I'll ignore event sourcing for the moment).  Perhaps you're able to encode all of your domain constraints in your database schema (letting the database take care of concurrency), which is great (we should all be so lucky!), though having the rules of the domain spread between our code and our DB schema introduces a potential point-of-conflict and means some category of changes to those rules requires a schema migration and all of that pain.  Alternatively, some optimistic concurrency control might be at work: if a concurrent update has gone through, we might go back to reload from the DB and onwards.

Because the actor and the concurrent `Map` combine to guard against concurrent modification (we've basically introduced pessimistic concurrency control), we can persist under the assumption of no concurrency, thus not paying a concurrency tax.  Likewise, we can dispense with loading the entity from the DB and verifying that invariants hold with every message: as long as there's at most one actor for this instance of the aggregate active at any one time and only such an actor updates the DB (and the command processing upholds the invariants, which you'd really hope was the case before), it suffices to load the entity into memory when the actor starts up and use the same in-memory state from command to command.  You're basically declaring the in-memory representation the source-of-truth with the DB representation only there for durability, and you've also created a single-source-of-truth for the domain logic and constraints.  As a side benefit, you've eliminated a majority of your DB load under concurrency (reads, DB concurrency resolution, retries under concurrency).

This sounds complex, but there are pre-existing implementations of this pattern: the concurrent `Map` is provided by Akka Cluster Sharding (note that a cluster of 1 node is perfectly acceptable) and I've basically just described Akka Persistence's `DurableStateBehavior` API.

Note that we've dramatically shifted the DB's workload: it's gone from a basically 1 read:1 write to 1 read:*n* writes (*n* >= 1).  You can now tune the DB for writes, especially if you're doing CQRS (and if you're publishing domain events for other bounded contexts, you're doing at least some CQRS already).  Shifting to event sourcing (e.g. Akka Persistence's `EventSourcedBehavior`), if done with fine-grained events, reduces the cost of the writes at the expense of the reads (since the events only concern part of the entity and can be small while reading a snapshot and then many events almost surely is more expensive than reading the whole state once), this optimization magnifies the benefits of our new write-heavy workload.

(Disclaimer: I'm employed by Lightbend, which is the primary developer of Akka, but this is the same answer I'd give even before that employment)

Comment: Much of that explanation makes sense. I can see how using Akka for an event sourced system would make sense. I've rolled my own solutions in the past and it is not as trivial as it first seems. Leaving persistence optimisations and concurrency control to Akka  and being less reliant on the transactional and locking aspects of an underlying database is quite tempting.